# Data contents are not set when notified in the foreground of cloud message

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a function of cloud functions that sends push notifications to Flutter apps using cloud messages. And I was able to send push notifications to the device, but when I looked at the contents of the message on the receiving device, the data was not stored.

How can I put a value in the notification message?
【index.js】

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const app = initializeApp();
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

// sendMessage
exports.pushSubmitFromApp = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const registrationToken = data.toToken;  
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: "testTitle",
      badge: "1",
      sound: "default"
    }
  };
  const option = {
    priority: "high"
  };

  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload, option)
  .then(pushResponse => {
    return { text: registrationToken };
  })
  .catch(error => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
  });
});
```

Flutter application side that calls the created cloud functions

```
   Future<void> callpPushSubmitFromApp() async {
    var myToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    try {
      var callable =
          FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("pushSubmitFromApp");
      await callable({"toToken": myToken});
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Flutter app code to receive

```
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
      debugPrint('Got a message in the foreground');
      debugPrint('message data: ${remoteMessage.data}');

      if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
        debugPrint('message is a notification');
        // On Android, foreground notifications are not shown, only when the app
        // is backgrounded.
      }
    });
```

I'm trying to debug the received code and stop it, but the remoteMessage data should contain the following values in Map format, but the contents are not included.

```
      title: "タイトル",
      badge: "1",
      sound: "default"
```

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.3, on macOS 13.3.1  darwin-arm64, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.10.3 on channel stable at /Users/user/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f92f44110e (4 days ago), 2023-06-01 18:17:33 -0500
    • Engine revision 2a3401c9bb
    • Dart version 3.0.3
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.0)
    • VS Code at /Users/user/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 32) (emulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```